# Winforms app doesn't respond to click events after disabling and then enabling timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I was making game like brick breaker in C# winforms and I wanted to implement restart button, when I click restart everything works fine(ball moves and bricks break) except board which doesn't move even though I'm clicking left and right buttons.

This is code the code where you lose if you hit the ground:

```
if(health < 1)
{
  winStatus.Text = "YOU HAVE LOST";
  Restart.Visible = true;
  timer1.Stop();
}
```

This is restart button logic:

```
private void Restart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //restart button
{
  health = 3;
  Health.Text = health.ToString();
  ball.Left = 402;
  ball.Top = 364;
  moveX = 4;
  moveY = 6;
  goUp = true;
  Restart.Visible = false;
  winStatus.Text = "";
  Board.Left = 342;
  Board.Top = 407;
  timer1.Start();
}
```

The code for the button events:

```
private void keyisdown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
  {
    moveLeft = true;
  }
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
  {
    moveRight = true;
  }
}

private void keyisup(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
  {
    moveLeft = false;
  }
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
  {
    moveRight = false;
  }
}
```

here is whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BrickBreaker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int level = 1;
        private int health = 3;

        private int moveX = 10;
        private int moveY = 10;
        private bool goRight = true;
        private bool goUp = true;

        bool moveRight, moveLeft;

        int speed = 30;

        int brickCount = 14;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.SetStyle(
                System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer,
                true);
            DoubleBuffered = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ball.Right > Width - 20)
            {
                goRight = false;
            }
            else if (ball.Left < 10)
            {
                goRight = true;
            }

            if (ball.Top < 10)
            {
                goUp = false;
            }
            else if (ball.Bottom > Height - 40)  //hitting ground
            {
                health--;
                if(health < 1)
                {
                    winStatus.Text = "YOU HAVE LOST";
                    Restart.Visible = true;
                    timer1.Stop();
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Health.Text = health.ToString();
                    ball.Left = 402;
                    ball.Top = 364;
                    moveX = 4;
                    moveY = 6;
                    goUp = true;
                   
                }
            }
            if (goRight)
            {
                ball.Left += moveX;
            }
            else
            {
                ball.Left -= moveX;
            }
            if (goUp)
            {
                ball.Top -= moveY;
            }
            else
            {
                ball.Top += moveY;
            }
            if (moveLeft && Board.Left > 20)
            {
                Board.Left -= speed;
            }
            if (moveRight && Board.Right < Width - 30)
            {
                Board.Left += speed;
            }
            foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
            {
                if (x is PictureBox && (string)x.Tag == "board") //touches board
                {
                    if (ball.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
                    {
                        if (ball.Bounds.Left - x.Bounds.Left < 40)
                        {
                            goRight = false;
                            moveX += 4;
                            moveY -= 1;
                        }
                        else if (ball.Bounds.Left - x.Bounds.Left >= 40 && ball.Bounds.Left - x.Bounds.Left < 72)
                        {
                            goRight = true;
                        }
                        else if (ball.Bounds.Left >= 72 && ball.Bounds.Left < 114)
                        {
                            moveY -= 4;
                            moveX -= 6;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            goRight = true;
                            moveX = +4;
                            moveY -= 1;
                        }

                        goUp = true;
                    }
                }
                if (x is PictureBox && (string)x.Tag == "brick") //touches brick
                {
                    if (ball.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
                    {
                        if (ball.Bottom <= x.Bottom)  //touches top side of brick
                        {
                            goUp = true;
                        }
                        else if (ball.Bottom > x.Bottom) //touches bot side of brick
                        {
                            moveY += 2;
                            goUp = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            goUp = false;
                        }
                        Controls.Remove(x);
                        brickCount--;
                    }
                }

                if (brickCount == 0 && timer1.Enabled)
                {
                    winStatus.Text = "YOU HAVE WON";
                    level+=1;
                    LevelNumber.Text = level.ToString();
                    timer1.Stop();
                }
            }
        }


        private void keyisdown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                moveLeft = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                moveRight = true;
            }
        }

        private void keyisup(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                moveLeft = false;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                moveRight = false;
            }
        }


        private void Restart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //restart button
        {
            health = 3;
            Health.Text = health.ToString();
            ball.Left = 402;
            ball.Top = 364;
            moveX = 4;
            moveY = 6;
            goUp = true;
            Restart.Visible = false;
            winStatus.Text = "";
            Board.Left = 342;
            Board.Top = 407;
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope my code is clear.

I have tried debugging the code and it actually goes into the button click methods but somehow the board doesn't move and I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: can you put the `board movement code` in the question text?

Comment: @HosseinSabziani I put the whole code can you check it? thanks

Comment: Do not call `Thread.Sleep(2000);` on the UI thread. It will lock up your form while the thread is sleeping.

Comment: How are keyisup/keyisdown hooked up?  Have you verified with a breakpoint they're being called?

Comment: So many magic numbers! There is no way you can keep track of those numbers and know what's going on in your code. You need to replace the magic numbers with constant variables or use the width and/or height of existing elements to compute the numbers.

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah I maybe use other method instead of thread.sleep.I also deleted it and it didn't change anything. and I did use height and width in code, sorry if it is bit messy I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: @AnonCoward yes I debugged it and it did go in lines when I clicked and released it.

Comment: @AkakiUjarashvili - Why would you use height and width in your code and then replace with number when you posted here?

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry sir I don't understand what you mean, exactly what did I replace and where?

Comment: @AkakiUjarashvili - You said, "I did use height and width in code", which I assume you were using `control.Height` instead of `48` in your code. But when you pasted it here you have numbers like `48` everywhere. I suspect I didn't understand your comment. Do you know what "magic numbers" are in relation to coding?

Comment: @Enigmativity oh I think I get it what you are saying, yes I did use magic numbers because when ball hit the borders it sometimes went through so I had to make border bit smaller so I did things like ball.bounds.left<40 and that kind of stuff. also do you have any idea why buttons do not work?

Comment: @AkakiUjarashvili - Don't use magic numbers, ever. And buttons do work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually problem was not the timer but the Restart button, when I set it's visibility to false it disappeared but it actually blocked Winforms from reacting to click events, after I set visibility and also Restart.Enabled to false then everything worked perfectly.